# Public Property unable to access Object Oriented PHP

Tags: php, html, css, oop, object-oriented-analysis

Please look at my databaseClass I Used a public property Called "connection" but I'm unable to access that property other .php  files. I'm learning OOP PHP. Please help me.
Here is the other File link http://pastebin.com/0Nh1uc8D

```
<?php 
require_once('config.php');//calling config.php
class Database{

    public $connection;//property

    //__construct();
    public function __construct(){
        $this->openDbConnection();
    }

    //method
    public function openDbConnection(){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            # code...
            die("Database Connection Failed Badly" . mysqli_error());
        }else{
            echo "DB Connected Successfully.";
        }
    }
}
//instance of the class
$database = new Database();
```

?>

Here is my confi.php file code 
http://pastebin.com/wQ9BFGf4

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How exactly have you tried to access the connection property in other files?

Comment: opps!! Here is the errors Notice: Undefined variable: database in /home/asad/workspace/public_html/oop/gallery/admin/inc/adminContent.php on line 16

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/asad/workspace/public_html/oop/gallery/admin/inc/adminContent.php on line 16

Comment: Without seeing more code, it's hard to be more specific, but basically, you're trying to access $database from somewhere it's not visible. The problem isn't that you can't access the property; the problem is you can't access the object itself.

Comment: unable to access the object, I created a Class instance Called "$database". I'm tying to connect the database using the object on this file http://pastebin.com/0Nh1uc8D  and I added all code please visit the links.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be *all* the code. Where are you including the file that contains the database class?

Comment: please check the code properly this is the class "Database" at the top. and $database is the instance of the class at the bottom of the class. I'm trying to access the the class via "$database" object other file http://pastebin.com/0Nh1uc8D

Answer (score 0):

For global access of classes and properties you can use it as static properties and methods:

```
class Database
{
    public static $connection;//property
    //method
    public static function openDbConnection()
    {
        self::$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            # code...
            die("Database Connection Failed Badly" . mysqli_error());
        }else{
            echo "DB Connected Successfully.";
        }
    }
}
// once "create" connection
Database::openDbConnection();
// and for all other files
var_dump(Database::$connection);
```

Comment: When someone unexpectedly wirtes `Database::$connection = 'WUT';` - it's your time to find a bug.

Comment: @u_mulder this is example only! And not explain many problems. But for you example -- this is developer fail )) Or you always deploy code like this? or you fix bugs on production instance?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$database` isn't definied at all by line 16 `adminContent.php`, if that is indeed all the code for that file in Pastebin.

You're getting distracted by the public property scope, that's working fine as-is. Public properties **are definitely** accessible from other files not included in other function or class scopes, but *only* if you've actually required the file that instantiates the `$database` object in the first place.

Without showing us more code on how `adminContent.php` is being included from, we can't debug why `$database` isn't instantiated by line 16.

Use a debugger to trace the code execution flow, or just add echo's or error_log's to both the database instantiation file and to adminContent.php code and run it. I think you'll find that `$database` isn't instantiated at all, or at least before you're accessing it in `adminContent.php`